# I am not able to send BTC in Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, wallet

I have `0.98 BTC` confirmed, but my wallet only lets me send `0.1 BTC`. My wallet has received a lot of small payments, what can I do? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you've hit the limit on number of transaction inputs for the wallet software (or total tx size).

Some wallets have a feature to "sweep dust", meaning consolidating all of those small UTXOs (unspent tx outputs). Note this will cost a small amount for tx fees. If it doesn't have this option, you can just make a few large transfers to an address you own using the same wallet (this will also cost tx fees).